# Создание таблиц SQL

Tags: sql

Здравствуйте! Вопрос наверное простой-по созданию внешних ключей в sql!
Есть ТАБЛИЦА1 со своими полями и ТАБЛИЦА2.

```
CREATE TABLE Holiday
(
HolidayID INT PRIMARY KEY,

TabelID int,

aaa varchar (50),

bbb varchar (50),

FOREIGN KEY (TabelID) REFERENCES Sotrdnik(TabelID)
)
GO
```

Потом ещё несколько таблиц в таком же духе, и только после этого таблица `Sotrdnik`, у которой `TabelID`  это `PRIMARY KEY`!

Возникает ошибка:

> Foreign key
> 'FK_Holiday__TabelID_09DE7BCC'
> references invalid table 'Sotrdnik'.
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
> Could not create constraint. See
> previous errors.

На сколько я понял, это потому, что ключ ссылается на ещё несуществующую таблицу, но таблицу Sotrdnik я не могу создать сначала, потому что на нее ещё верхние ссылаются.

Как это решить? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Неплохо было бы указать, какую СУБД используете.
В общем случае сначала создаете все таблицы, а после этого добавляете внешние ключи

```
ALTER TABLE Holiday ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Holiday_Sotrudnik
  FOREIGN KEY (TableID) REFERENCES Sotrudnik(TableID) ) GO
```

Comment: т.е. сразу при создании таблицы внешний ключ нельзя прописать?

Comment: Раз вы говорите, что порядок таблиц никак не изменить, то нельзя. Если создание таблиц и внешних ключей выполняется в одном скрипте, то без разницы

Comment: ок, спасибо! а ещё такой момент: если мне нужно несколько внешних сделать, в одном ALTER TABLE это можно? через запятую, and или как?

Comment: @wicS, Не следует задавать вопросы в комментариях к ответу. Если у вас есть другой вопрос, создайте отдельную тему.